# What does the notation $c = [1:\beta]$ mean?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, notation

I have been reading a online-book/blog/material on Quantum Mechanics, when I encountered a notation on a page and I have no idea what it means. See if you can help.

[Here](http://thisquantumworld.com/wp/the-mystique-of-quantum-mechanics/indistinguishable-particles/)'s the link and follows the paragraph where I am stuck.

> Observe that exchanging either the incoming or the out­going
>   par­ti­cles is tan­ta­mount to exchanging the two alter­na­tives and,
>   cor­re­spond­ingly, the two ampli­tudes, so that A2 takes the place of
>   A1 and vice versa. Since the two ampli­tudes have the same
>   mag­ni­tude, there is a com­plex number c of unit mag­ni­tude such
>   that A2 = A1 c. In other words, mul­ti­pli­ca­tion by c = **[1:β]**
>   rep­re­sents an exchange of the incoming or out­going particles.
>
> If the incoming or out­going par­ti­cles are exchanged twice, then (i)
>   A1 gets mul­ti­plied by $c^2$ and (ii) the orig­inal sit­u­a­tion is
>   restored. Thus A1 = A1 $c^2$, whence it fol­lows that $c^2$ = **[1:2β]** = 1.
>   This means that 2β must be equal to an inte­gral mul­tiple of 360°,
>   and this leaves us with two pos­si­bil­i­ties: β = 0°, in which case
>   A2 = A1, or β = 180°, in which case A2 = −A1.

I have put the notation in bold. What is it that the writer means exactly by $[1:\beta] \ \ and  \ [1: 2 \beta]$ ?

:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The author uses this weird notation $[c:\gamma]$ to represent complex numbers. It means:  c is short for the mag­ni­tude $|c|$ of c, $\gamma$ is the phase of c.

I have never seen this before either ;-).

The author explains it earlier in his book, check out this [link](http://thisquantumworld.com/wp/the-technique-of-quantum-mechanics/complex-numbers/).

Comment: The colon is interesting but the square brackets are somewhat standard for polar coordinates and the complex numbers in polar form, see e.g. pages 1 and 66-67 of http://www.cimt.plymouth.ac.uk/projects/mepres/alevel/fpure_ch3.pdf

Comment: I've never seen it before. I've been studying physics and math for 5 years now.